# LinkButton postbackurl Error in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, linkbutton, yahoo-messenger

I want to send a Message by clicking on a `LinkButton` through yahoo messenger in Asp.net. Some times It works and sometimes I get this errors: `Windows can not access the spesified device, path or file. You may not have appropriate permission to access this item` and also  `Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 400` This is my code in VB, What is wrong with it?

```
Protected Sub LinkButton2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LinkButton2.Click
    Dim idname As String = "YMID"
    Dim message As String = "Hello, This is my YM message"
    Dim sendim As String = String.Format("ymsgr:SendIM?{0}&m={1}", idname, message)
    LinkButton2.PostBackUrl = (sendim)
End Sub
```

Comment: Try to use hyperlink and set href to your value. Link button will not work.

Comment: I know this method. But I want it work with clicking. By the way it works but sometimes get the error.

Comment: Any specific occasion when you get an error?